# Office 365 Add-in Sign-in via 365 account or Facebook

Tags: ms-office, office365api

I'm creating Office 365 Content App Add-in and I would like to implement sign-up via Office 365 account, facebook and google.

I already implemented those authentifications on the web part, but have no idea how to do it in Office 365 Add-in. I manage to open popup with Office login, but how to transfer callback back to main opener if its on different domain?

I have seen it on others Add-ins so it have to work. Has anyone experiences with this?